# getting binary data when using POST request in httr package

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

I am using the POST function in httr library to get some data and the code is shown below.

```
library(httr)

url = "https://xxxx:xxx@api.xxx/_search" #omitted for privacy
a = POST(url,body = query,encode = "json")
```

The query is shown below in the appendix. `a$content` is giving me a whole bunch of a hexadecimal numbers on which I have to use another function before I can get some useful data.

Ultimately I wish to get a data frame by using `b = fromJSON(a$content)`. So far in order to get any data I have to use:

```
chr<-function(n){rawToChar(as.raw(n))}
b = jsonlite::fromJSON(chr(a$content))
data = b$hits$hits$`_source`
```

This seems inefficient considering that I am parsing in the data through a local function to get the final data. So my questions are as follows:

1. Am I using the POST function correctly to get the query?
2. Is there a more efficient (faster) way of getting my data into a data frame?

Appendix:

```
query = '
{
  "_source": [
    "start","source.country_codes",
    "dest.country_codes"
    ],
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": [
    {
    "bool": {
    "must_not": [
    {
    "range": {
    "start": {
    "lte": "2013-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
    }
    },
    {
    "range": {
    "start": {
    "gt": "2016-05-19T00:00:00"
    }
    }
    }
    ]
    }
    }
    ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 5):

1. POST function looks good.
2. `js<-fromJSON(content(a,as="text"))`