# Get non html content from rvest_session object

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I am trying to get a text file from a URL. From the browser, its fairly simple. I just have to "save as" the from the URL and I get the file I want. At first, i had some trouble logging in using rvest (see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352322/how-to-get-txt-file-from-password-protected-website-jsp-in-r][1])(I uploaded a couple of probably useful picture there). When I use the following code:

```
fileurl <- "http://www1.bolsadecaracas.com/esp/productos/dinamica/downloadDetail.jsp?symbol=BNC&dateFrom=20190101&dateTo=20210101&typePlazo=nada&typeReg=T"
session(fileurl)
```

I get the following (note how I am redirected to a different URL, as happens in the browser when you try to get to the fileurl without first logging in):

```
<session> http://www1.bolsadecaracas.com/esp/productos/dinamica/downloadDetail.jsp?symbol=BNC&dateFrom=20190101&dateTo=20210101&typePlazo=nada&typeReg=T
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
  Size:   84
```

I managed to log in using the following code:

```
#Define URLs
loginurl <- "http://www1.bolsadecaracas.com/esp/usuarios/customize.jsp"
fileurl <- "http://www1.bolsadecaracas.com/esp/productos/dinamica/downloadDetail.jsp?symbol=BNC&dateFrom=20190101&dateTo=20210101&typePlazo=nada&typeReg=T"

#Create session
pgsession <- session(loginurl)
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]   #Get form

#Create a fake submit button as form does not have one
fake_submit_button <- list(name = NULL,
                           type = "submit",
                           value = NULL,
                           checked = NULL,
                           disabled = NULL,
                           readonly = NULL,
                           required = FALSE)
attr(fake_submit_button, "class") <- "input"    
pgform[["fields"]][["submit"]] <- fake_submit_button

#Create and submit filled form
filled_form<-html_form_set(pgform, login="******", passwd="******")
session_submit(pgsession, filled_form)

#Jump to new url
loggedsession <- session_jump_to(pgsession, url = fileurl)

#Output
loggedsession
```

It seems to me that the login was succesful, as the session output is the exact same size than the .txt file when I download it and I am no longer redirected. See the output.

```
<session> http://www1.bolsadecaracas.com/esp/productos/dinamica/downloadDetail.jsp?symbol=BNC&dateFrom=20190101&dateTo=20210101&typePlazo=nada&typeReg=T
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
  Size:   32193
```

However, whenever I try to extract the content of the session with read_html() or the like, i get the following error: "Error: Page doesn't appear to be html.". I dont know if it has anything to do with the "Type:  text/plain" of the session.

When I run

```
loggedsession[["response"]][["content"]]
```

I get

```
  [1] 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 7c 30 32 2f 30 31 2f 32 30 31 39 7c 52 7c 31 34 2c 39 30 7c 31 35 2c
  [34] 30 30 7c 31 37 2c 38 33 7c 31 33 2c 35 30 7c 39 7c 31 33 2e 35 33 33 7c 32 30 33 2e 30 36 30 2c 31
  [67] 39 7c 0a 7c 30 33 2f 30 31 2f 32 30 31 39 7c 52 7c 31 35 2c 30 30 7c 31 37 2c 39 38 7c 31 37 2c 39
```

Any help on how to extract the text file??? Would be greatly appreciated.

PS:
At one point, just playing with functions I managed to get something that would have worked with httr::: GET(fileurl). That was after playing with rvest functions and managing to log in. However, after closing and opening RStudio I was not able to get the same output with that function.

Comment: so you got back what looks like hexadecimal. Anything here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404921/getting-binary-data-when-using-post-request-in-httr-package  `rawToChar(as.raw(n))` - though that looks like a patch

Comment: I believe you can use httr content function to convert the data.  Here is example to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459356/httr-csv-content-reading-as-integer-instead-of-double. The are better question/answers out there if you look.

Answer (score 0):

Because `rvest` uses `httr` package internally, you can use the `httr` and `base` to save your file. The key to the solution is that your `response` (in terms of the `httr` package) is in the session object:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

httr::content(loggedsession$response, as = "text") %>%
   cat(file = "your_file.txt")
```

More importantly, if your file were binary (e.g. a zip archive), you would have to do:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

httr::content(loggedsession$response, as = "raw") %>%
    writeBin(con = 'your_file.zip')
```